# DynamoDB contains value in an array using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-dynamodb, contains, aws-sdk

I'm studying DynamoDB using rails and I got a doubt.
I not be able to find a solution on web, so If you can solve it I'll thank.

The doubt is how can I find values into array saved on a table, for example:

I have a lot of data in my_table where there are fields called "numbers" that are arrays like:

```
[1,2,3,4]
[3,4,5,6]
[1,3,4,7]
[4,7,8,10]
[8,9,12,14]
[12,14,16,20]
```

So, I want select all entries that contains numbers 1,3,4. In this case four results.

So, my code is

```
result = dynamodb.scan({
    table_name: "my_table",
    select: "ALL_ATTRIBUTES",
    attributes_to_get: ["numbers"],
    scan_filter: {
        "numbers" => {
            attribute_value_list: [1,3,4],
            comparison_operator: "CONTAINS"
        }
    }
})
```

But I get this error: One or more parameter values were invalid: Invalid number of argument(s) for the CONTAINS ComparisonOperator

How can I do this action using dynamo DB?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if it works, I know from experience that DynamoDB is very painful to filter.

```
result = dynamodb.scan(
  table_name: 'my_table',
  expression_attribute_values: { 
    ':one' => 1,
    ':two' => 2,
    ':three' => 3,
    ':four' => 4
  },
  filter_expression: 'contains(numbers, :one) OR contains(numbers, :two) OR contains(numbers, :three) OR contains(numbers, :four)'
)
```

I can't think of anything simpler currently, the method you linked is marked as deprecated, instead you should use `expression_attribute_values` and `filter_expression`.

Comment: Hi Nabeel,

I'll try it, but the filter is dynamic, then this way can be unusual.

But this example give me a light...i'll test.

Comment: One thing to note is that scan filtering will still cost you the same in terms of item reads/writes as if it were a full scan. This is because filtering is applied after the data has been fetched but before it is returned to you, you could very well filter it yourself (but that might include having to deal with pagination, 1 MB size limit, etc).

Comment: I tried your way and another way, but now I got "stack level too deep" error, so, I quit Dynamodb and back to postgres, I got the result in 2 lines code.
In the future I'll try DynamoDB, maybe...